# OpenCL how to change the memory address of cl_mem?

Tags: opencl, matrix-multiplication

I want to do a sub-matrix multiplication. Say I have a function:

```
void MatMul(cl_mem A, cl_mem B, cl_mem C, int M, int K, int N)
```

where A is M*K, B is K*N, C is M*N, and A, B, C are all row major 1 dimension array passed by host memory `float *h_A, *h_B, *hC` with the following function:

```
void ocl_push_array(cl_mem d_x, float *h_x, int n){
    size_t data_size = sizeof(float)*n;
    err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, d_x, CL_TRUE, 0, data_size, h_x, 0, NULL, NULL);
}
```

> 

**I want to ask**:

if I want to do sub-matrix multiplication, say slicing A by row:

```
    // cl_mem A, B, C;
    for(int x=0; x<M; x+=16)
    {
        cl_mem A_sub = (cl_mem)((float *)A+x*K);
        cl_mem C_sub = (cl_mem)((float *)C+x*N);
        if((M-x+1)>=16)
            MatMul(A_sub, B, C_sub, 16, K, N);
        else
            MatMul(A_sub, B, C_sub, M-x+1, K, N);
    }
```

Is it the right code to do this operation? I got a run time error says: `"CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT" (-38)` when it assigns arguments to OpenCL kernel (`clSetKernelArg`).

The reason I want to do this operation is that I found the matrix multiplication got wrong answers when my input matrix A and B become big.

> 

My OpenCL kernel is:

```
#define BLOCK_SIZE 16

#define AS(i, j) As[j + i * BLOCK_SIZE]
#define BS(i, j) Bs[j + i * BLOCK_SIZE]

__kernel void
matrixMul(__global float* A, __global float* B, __global float* C, 
   __local float* As, __local float* Bs, int uiWA, int uiWB)
{
    int bx = get_group_id(0);
    int by = get_group_id(1);
    int tx = get_local_id(0);
    int ty = get_local_id(1);
    int aBegin = uiWA * BLOCK_SIZE * by;
    int aEnd   = aBegin + uiWA - 1;
    int aStep  = BLOCK_SIZE;
    int bBegin = BLOCK_SIZE * bx;
    int bStep  = BLOCK_SIZE * uiWB;
    float Csub = 0.0f;
    for (int a = aBegin, b = bBegin; a <= aEnd; a += aStep, b += bStep) {
        AS(ty, tx) = A[a + uiWA * ty + tx];
        BS(ty, tx) = B[b + uiWB * ty + tx];
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE); 
        #pragma unroll
        for (int k = 0; k < BLOCK_SIZE; ++k)
        Csub += AS(ty, k) * BS(k, tx);
            barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
        }
        C[get_global_id(1) * get_global_size(0) + get_global_id(0)] = Csub; 
    }
```

and the size is:

```
#define BLOCK_SIZE 16

size_t localWorkSize[] = {BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE};
size_t globalWorkSize[] = {shrRoundUp(BLOCK_SIZE, N), shrRoundUp(BLOCK_SIZE, M)};

size_t shrRoundUp(int group_size, int global_size) 
{
    int r = global_size % group_size;
    if(r == 0) 
    {
        return global_size;
    } else 
    {
        return global_size + group_size - r;
    }
}
```

the code is adopted from Nvidia OpenCL matrix multiplication sample. My GPU is: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this:

```
cl_mem A_sub = (cl_mem)((float *)A+x*K);
```

Because cl_mem is an object in OpenCL, which is actually a complex data structure instead of just a data pointer. It maintains information such as data pointer to the actually memory, reference to the object, memory properties and so on. Different run-times may even have different implementations of cl_mem object. That's why you got the CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT error message.

What you can do to get wanted data for the sub matrix is one of the followings:

1. define two new cl_mem objects, and use a separate kernel to do
   the copy work.
2. use clEnqueueCopyBuffer function to copy the data at the host
   code domain.
3. use CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR to memory buffer, and then use
   clEnqueueMapBuffer map the GPU memory to host memory pointer, and
   then modify the memory content by using the mapped host memory
   pointer, when you finish, unmap the pointer to return the GPU memory
   to the device memory domain.